# Referential Integrity - Indirect Foreign Key In "Depth"

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key, referential-integrity

**Question**

What is the best practice for ensuring a Key from a "Grand-Parent" or "Great Grand-Parent" table is maintained when a "Child" or "Grand-Child" table is created from multiple relationship trees.

**Details Since That Question Doesn't Likely Make Sense**

I am attempting to build a database for keeping track of the execution status of automated processes running in our environment.

In general we have a "Job" which triggers one or more "Executables" and those "Executables" can run tasks for one or more customers.  We will then have 2 logging tables, one that tracks when a "Job" was started, and another that will log the Success vs Failure status of each "ExecutableCustomer" instance.

A Planned Simplified Schema is below:
[image: ER Diagram]

When we right the record to the `JobExecutableCustomerExecutionLog`, I would like to ensure that the `Job.ID` value associated with `JobExecutionLog.ID` value matches the `Job.ID` value associated with `JobExecutableCustomer.ID`.

Normally I would handle this with a `Foreign Key` but since `Job.ID` is not stored on `JobExecutableCustomer`, `JobExecutableCustomerExecutionLog` nor `JobExecutionLog`.  The Relationship is indirect.

**Example:**

I have 2 jobs, "Send Email" and "Send Text Message".  "Send Email" initiates a single executable which belongs to 1 Customer. "Send Text Message" has 2 executables (both of which execute for the same customer). I want to make sure that when the record is written to `JobExecutableCustomerExecutionLog` for "Send Email" the `Job.ID` associated with `JobExecutableCustomerExecutionLog.JobExecutableCustomerID` and `JobExecutableCustomerExecutionLog.JobExecutionLogID` (after walking the relationships up) actually belong to the `Job.ID` for "Send Email" not "Send Text Message".

**As I see it I have 2 options:**

1. Push the value from `Job.ID` into all the child tables, and make it part of the `Foreign Key`
2. Have another process (`Trigger` or `Indexed View`) ensure the relationships for me

I personally don't like the idea of pushing the `Job.ID` value on all the other child tables, so I am leaning towards using a `Trigger` or something else to handle it.  I didn't know if those were my only two options or if I have the ability to configure a "normal" `Foreign Key` to traverse the relationships all the way up.  In some kind of `Cascade` or something else.

Comment: Well, you have 2 general avenues. Either declarative integrity (thorough FKs), your option 1, or procedural, through triggers (option 2) or procedures. With "procedures" I mean for example having an INSERT procedure for the last tables in the chain (the grandchildren or grand-grandchildren that have 2 or more paths from the same root above. This INSERT procedure will take care of integrity and you restrict INSERT access to the tables only through them. (you may need similar logic for UPDATEs if the PK/FKs in the middle path are updatable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I personally don't like the idea of pushing the Job.ID value on all the other child tables

Why not?  The obvious solution is to make JobID the leading PK/clustered index column on all the child tables.  And it ensures optimal performance for accessing all these tables by JobID.

Generally whenever you have an "identifying relationship" aka "child table" aka "weak entity" the child table should use a compound primary key whose leading columns are also the foreign key to the parent table.  Something like this:

```
create table Parent
(
  ParentId int not null identity,
  constraint pk_Parent
    primary key(ParentId)
)

create table Child
(
  ParentId int not null, 
  ChildId int not null identity, 
  constraint pk_Child 
    primary key (ParentId,ChildId),
  constraint fk_Child_Parent
    foreign key (ParentId) references Parent(ParentId)
    on delete cascade
)
create table GrandChild
(
  ParentId int not null references Parent, 
  ChildId int not null, 
  GrandChildId int not null identity,
  constraint pk_GrandChild 
    primary key (ParentId,ChildId,GrandChildId),
  constraint fk_GrandChild_Child
    foreign key (ParentId) references Parent(ParentId)
    on delete cascade
)
```

Comment: As I understand it, the best practice is to create a `FK` to the immediate parent, so the relationship is established.  Maintaining an Key from a higher level parent (Grand-Parent, Great Grand-Parent) on a "child" table is recommended against, because it removes some of the normalization.

Now this may be an instance where "breaking" the rules on purpose is a good idea because it is done for a specific reason (we want to query/validate by Job.ID later).  

Is that the general idea here, or are you saying that it is a best practice to always copy any and all parent keys to a child table?

Comment: Yes "it is a best practice to always copy any and all parent keys to a child table".  It provides the referential integrity, enables you to have a single FK and a single data structure per table (the alternate designs all require multiple indexes per child table), and it optimizes the performance of access by parent key, and cascading operations.

Comment: Thank you for that input.  (Where I work that is how we have most of the tables set up, but it is sort of talked about as a design flaw not a design advantage).  Has this always been the best practice, and I was told incorrect information or has the best practice changed due to advances in understanding or technology?

Comment: There's always been controversy over composite keys in the SQL Server community.  There's an old, old practice of slapping `int identity primary key` on every table.  But the justifications for it (to the extent they were ever valid) are not very compelling.   IMO this has always been the optimal design for performance for true parent_table/child_table hierarchies.

Comment: I suppose in this instance, moving down the `Job.ID` value (at the very least but presumably all parent keys) would run cleaner, faster and be more obvious to diagnose, than trying to build a `trigger` or some other alternative to handle that.  Because I need the same `Job.ID` to match coming from 2 different places.  That is what `FK` were designed to do, and a few extra `INT` `columns` on the `table` shouldn't change the `paging` for the `table` or `indexes` too significantly.  Thank you very much for talking through this with me!

Comment: @KirkSaunders : *"Maintaining an Key from a higher level parent (Grand-Parent, Great Grand-Parent) on a 'child' table is recommended against, because it removes some of the normalization."* Not sure I fully understand this, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129649/linear-database-design/61144332#61144332

Comment: @DamirSudarevic As I understand it, because the higher level parent keys would be duplicated on the child table, and they can be inferred from the parent table.  It is an "unnecessary" duplication of higher level parent keys, and thus un-does some of the benefits of normalization.  Namely the disk space savings. (I know disk space is cheep now so that isn't really a reason for doing/not doing something.  That is just what I was taught.  Maybe my understanding of normalization is incorrect.)

Answer (score 2):

An *example* of how data integrity can be maintained using `FKs`.
I have modified the model a bit to allow for an executable to be a part of more than one job. The assumption is that when an executable runs, it runs for all customers associated with that executable. Your ERD does not show constraints, so there is some guessing involved.

---

```
-- Customer CUS exists.
--
customer {CUS}
      PK {CUS}
```

```
-- Executable EXE exists.
--
executable {EXE}
        PK {EXE}
```

```
-- Executable EXE runs task for customer {CST}.
--
customer_exe {EXE, CST}
          PK {EXE, CST}

FK1 {EXE} REFERENCES executable {EXE}
FK2 {CUS} REFERENCES customer   {CUS}
```

```
-- Job JOB exists.
--
job {JOB}
 PK {JOB}
```

```
-- Step number STP# of job JOB
-- runs executable EXE.
--
job_step {JOB, STP#, EXE}
      PK {JOB, STP#}
      SK {JOB, STP#, EXE}

FK1 {JOB} REFERENCES job {JOB}
FK2 {EXE} REFERENCES executable {EXE}
```

An assumption is that tasks write to `log_` tables,
so some redundancy is expected: like `EXE` in `log_job`;
still `FKs` prevent anomalies.

```
-- Executable EXE ran as step number STP#
-- of job JOB on DTE (date-time).
--
log_job {DTE_J, JOB, STP#, EXE}
     PK {DTE_J, JOB, STP#}
     SK {DTE_J, JOB, STP#, EXE}

      FK {JOB, STP#, EXE} REFERENCES
job_step {JOB, STP#, EXE}
```

```
-- Executable EXE ran for customer CUS,
-- with success result RES, on DTE_C (date-time),
-- as step number STP# of job JOB, which ran on DTE_J.
--
log_cus {DTE_J, JOB, STP#, CUS, EXE, DTE_C, RES}
     PK {DTE_J, JOB, STP#, CUS}

    FK1 {DTE_J, JOB, STP#, EXE} REFERENCES
log_job {DTE_J, JOB, STP#, EXE}

         FK2 {EXE, CST} REFERENCES
customer_exe {EXE, CST}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```